# How can I make a foreground service like fire base cloud messaging?

Tags: android, web, websocket

I am a full stack developer. I'm wondering to find a solution in android background. I'm thinking to write a push notification system for all mobile device types (android,ios) and for web browsers (i mean for web clients). I already have a web-socket server written with nodejs and socketIO. My problem is how can i handle web-socket responses on mobiledevices. At the start point to decide make it with foreground services. But i don't want to show to the users any notification icon on the top. I can not resolve this problem and i don't want to use FCM(Firebase Cloud Messagging) or any third party product i want to make my own background system. I'am ready to learn any programming language for that and if required to work all day and all night.
Thank you very much !

Comment: "But i don't want to show to the users any notification icon on the top" -- you do not have a choice.

Comment: how to do that Whatsapp or facebook or viber ?

Comment: AFAIK, they use FCM.

Comment: thank you for your answer :)